# Build OpenStack Images

Tags: openstack, kvm

What's the easiest way to create image file for OpenStack?
Is it with KVM?

If so, are those articles the right ones: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/buildbot-setup-for-virtual-machines/

Answer (score 0):

See [Creating images manually](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_creating_images_manually.html) for steps to manually create images for OpenStack.

The easiest way is downloading ready images instead of making it on your own. read this [Obtaining images](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/content/ch_obtaining_images.html)